# change one Chair for two cochair

Tags: templates

May someone tell me how to change in this template the field "Chair" for two fields of "Cochair"? thanks in advance for your help!

https://github.com/shumway/asudis

Answer (score 2):

This is rather simple, you just need to edit the file `asudis.sty` with a text editor.

1. Look for "chair" in the file and modify accordingly

   ```
   \newcommand{\chair}[1]{\renewcommand{\@chair}{#1}}
   \newcommand{\cochair}[1]{\renewcommand{\@cochair}{#1}}
   \newcommand{\@chair}{\tt$\backslash$\string chair}
   \newcommand{\@cochair}{\tt$\backslash$\string cochair}
   ```
2. Scroll down in the file and modify the `\maketitle` section as following:

   ```
   \begin{center}
   \singlespace
   Approved \@defensemonth\ \@defenseyear\ by the\\
   Graduate Supervisory Committee:\\
   \ \\
   \@chair,  Chair\\
   \@cochair,  Cochair\\    
   \@memberOne\\
   \@memberTwo\\
   \@memberThree\\
   \@memberFour
   \end{center}
   ```
3. Define the co-chair in the `dis.tex` file.

[image: dis]

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the template, you can patch the `\maketitle` macro to insert the relevant co-chair content:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{geometry} % Just to make asudis work
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % Just to make asudis work
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Just to make asudis work
\newcommand{\bibsection}{} % Just to make asudis work
\usepackage{asudis} % https://github.com/shumway/asudis

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cochair}[1]{\def\@cochair{#1}} % New \cochair{<cochair>} macro
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{Chair}{Cochair}{}{} % Change Chair > Cochair
\patchcmd{\maketitle}{\@memberOne}{\@cochair, Cochair \\ \@memberOne}{}{} % Add another Cochair
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%-----------------------front matter

\pagenumbering{roman}
\title{Your Title Goes Here}
\author{Your name}
\degreeName{Doctor of Philosophy}
\paperType{Dissertation}
\defensemonth{Some month}
\defenseyear{Some year}
\gradmonth{Graduation month}
\gradyear{Graduation year}
\chair{Your chair}
\cochair{Your cochair}
\memberOne{Your first member}
\memberTwo{Your second member}
\memberThree{Your third member}
\memberFour{Your fourth member}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

This makes the use of `\cochair{<cochair>}` mandatory.